# Docker - Backup Containers in /var/lib/docker/vfs/dir

Tags: backup, docker, containers

I have noticed that all the data for the docker containers is located in the folder "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir"

I have research different techniques for backing up docker containers but I haven't seen anyone backup the containers directly without using docker. It seems like we are all missing a trick when backing up docker containers.

My question is, has anyone else backed up their docker containers in the folder: "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir"?

Example: I would create a TAR file of the directory "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir" and move the TAR file onto another server.

EDIT: I have data only containers which keep my persistent data separate to the worker containers. When browsing "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir", I can see all the persistent data. I am trying to think of a reason why I wouldn't simply rsync all the folders and files onto another server for a backup.

Answer (score 0):

There is no more sense to backup the containers. They are just the  instances of docker images.  Every time you run the container it is created from the docker image.

There is a data which we want to keep after the container will be stopped or removed and you can use external volumes for it.

To get the image on the other server you can save it on the docker registry or just save the Dockerfile and recreate the image on the new server.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have data only containers which keep my persistent data separate to the worker containers. When browsing "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir", I can see all the persistent data. I am trying to think of a reason why I wouldn't simply rsync all the folders and files onto another server for a backup.